# Ubuntu 20.04 - Disabling unwanted audio hotkey (CTRL, 1) breaks Printscreen button

Tags: ubuntu, audio, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, screenshot

I recently discoverd an annoying shortcut in Ubuntu 20.04 while playing a game: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> (not <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> at the same time; I just tap <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, wait a tiny amount of time, and then hit <kbd>1</kbd>, and then this annoying pop-up for "line out" appears, and my sound output has been muted. This is extremely annoying when playing games.

[image]

---

So, I searched Stackexchange sites to find a solution, and came across [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461701/disable-all-unity-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-command-line) and tried this command to disable all annoying hotkeys and keyboard shortcuts:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys active false
```

However, this turned off print-screen and a couple other things I need (thought it would only impact audio hotkeys), and even worse, **the annoying <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> hotkey still functions!** So, I attempt to use the "undo" command from the same question:

---

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys active true
```

... and now my print-screen button is broken. When I hit it, it brings up some settings GUI and jumps to the "Keyboard shortcuts" section.

[image]

---

If I attempt to re-map the print-screen button, it seems that Ubuntu thinks my print-screen button is some kind of "Tools" button.

[image]

---

Oddly, commands like <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> work, and detect the button as "Print", but ever since originally attempting to disable this unwanted audio shortcut, just <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> on its own no longer works. I've swapped out 3 different 101-US style keyboards to make sure it's not some keyboard-specific `Fn`-lock or something like that.

To my question:

- How do I disable this annoying Ubuntu audio hotkey?
- How do I get my <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button registering correctly once again?

Thanks.